# How to find this limit?!

Tags: calculus

How do I apply L'Hopital's Rule to the following limit:

$\lim_{x->\infty}e^{tx-(\ln(x))^2/2}$

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clear that the answer is $0$ if $t\le 0$.

For $t\gt 0$, I would not use L'Hospitals's Rule directly on the function, but instead look at the behaviour of the exponent.

For $t\gt 0$, we "know" that $tx-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2 x$ blows up as $x\to\infty$. It follows that our original function blows up.

If we want to be formal about it, rewrite the exponent as 
$$x\left(t+ \frac{\ln^2 x}{2x}\right).\tag{1}$$
We will use L'Hospital's Rule to show that 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln^2 x}{2x}=0.$$
One application of L'Hospitals's Rule shows that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln^2 x}{2x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln x}{2x}.$$
A second application of the Rule shows that the limit is $0$.

It follows that $t+ \frac{\ln^2 x}{2x}$ has limit $t$, and therefore the limit in (1) is "$\infty$," or, if one prefers, does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

$$
e^{tx-1/2\,\log(x)^2}=e^{tx}/x^{1/2 
\,\log x}
$$

Comment: $e^{\log(x)}=x$

Comment: $e^{\frac{1}{2} (\ln x)^2}= (e^{\ln x})^{\frac{1}{2}\ln x} = x^{\frac{1}{2}\ln x}$.